# Dynamic measure % dax formula

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

Hope you all are doing well and safe!!

I have a question regarding Power BI dax ; i want to create a new measure to calculate the needed quantity of raw material used to create a product based on the demand for a specific month

Comment: Hi! In order for people to be able to help you, you need to provide more information. Consider sharing an example of the data, what you've accomplished so far and your specific difficulty. The community is great, but without it, your questions tends to be voted down and closed. Have a look at the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please edit your post to add more detail regarding your data, the calculation you expect to use and any other pertinent information about your model. Please also share what you have tried already. Unfortunately without this, it will be difficult to help you.